# Onclick javascript function working only on second click

Tags: javascript, html, css, events, click

```js
function toggleDivFunction() {
  var arrowElement = document.getElementById("arrowRight");
  var showElement = document.getElementById("dropdownText");
  arrowElement.onclick = function() {
    if (showElement.style.display == 'none') {
      showElement.style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById("arrowRight").style = "transform: rotate(+90deg)";
    } else {
      showElement.style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById("arrowRight").style = "transform: rotate(0deg)";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="dropdownHeader">TOP <span id="arrowRight" class="arrowRight" onclick="toggleDivFunction();"> > </span></p>
<div class="dropdownText" id="dropdownText"><p>TEXT TO BE SHOWN</p></div>
```

The problem is that the `dropdownText` div only shows up after a second click on the `arrowRight` span.
I have seen it as a common problem, but still failed in finding a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: just remove this: arrowElement.onclick = function() { }
You are adding an event listener in the function that's supposed to capture your event. No big deal!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need to `bind` a `click` event handler inside another `click` event handler. You have to use a single `click` event handler.

The `show/hide` functionality belongs to second `click` event handler and this is `binded` to your `span` DOM element after first `click`.

```js
function toggleDivFunction () {
   var arrowElement = document.getElementById ("arrowRight");
   var showElement = document.getElementById ("dropdownText");
   if(showElement.style.display == 'none')
   {
      showElement.style.display = 'block'; 
      document.getElementById("arrowRight").style = "transform: rotate(+90deg)";
   }
   else
   {
      showElement.style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById("arrowRight").style = "transform: rotate(0deg)";
   }
}
```

```html
<p class="dropdownHeader">TOP <span id="arrowRight" class="arrowRight" onclick="toggleDivFunction();"> > </span></p>
<div class="dropdownText" id="dropdownText">
<p>TEXT TO BE SHOWN</p></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just adding to approved answer.

Check for `showElement.style.display == ''`.
Additionally, for switching to flex on first click itself, if you are using `display = 'none'` as default.

Example:

```
..
if (showElement.style.display == 'none' || showElement.style.display == '') {
..
```

if the style of text is `display = 'none'`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to assign your event handlers earlier:

```
window.onload=toggleDivFunction;
```

and remove the *onclick='toggleDivFunction()'*, its unneccessary then and oldfashioned.

Your code assigns a listener when an event is triggered (toggleDivFunction). To trigger the listener (arrowElement.onclick) you need to cause another event doing a *second click*.

Answer (score 0):

remove the `arrowElement.onclick = function() {}`

**Why?**

> you have already apply the function in `onclick=toggleDivFunction()` with `arrowRight` .so
>   first execute the `toggleDivFunction()` then to perform the `Dom` `arrowElement.onclick` .use any one of the onclick function ,not both

```js
function toggleDivFunction() {
  var arrowElement = document.getElementById("arrowRight");
  var showElement = document.getElementById("dropdownText");
    if (showElement.style.display == 'none') {
      showElement.style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById("arrowRight").style = "transform: rotate(+90deg)";
    } else {
      showElement.style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById("arrowRight").style = "transform: rotate(0deg)";
    }
}
```

```html
<p class="dropdownHeader">TOP <span id="arrowRight" class="arrowRight" onclick="toggleDivFunction();"> > </span></p>
<div class="dropdownText" id="dropdownText">
  <p>TEXT TO BE SHOWN</p>
</div>
```